# When there're NaNs and you want to use groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Ok, I have a dataframe with a Timestamp index that I want to group by. It's of the form:

```
                         key1           key2       value
 2014-02-03 12:00:00     22             32         98.89
 2014-02-03 12:00:00     23             33         99.25
 2014-02-03 12:00:00     24             34         99.78
 2014-02-03 15:00:00     22             32         96.54
 2014-02-03 15:00:00     23             33         97.21
 2014-02-03 15:00:00     24             34         98.59
 2014-02-03 18:00:00     22             33         97.41
```

so as you can see, each 3 indexes there's a jump forward of 3 hours. I want to group by index using the mean as function. I use:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level=0).mean()
```

The problem is that I want to be sure that if there's a NaN (for instance, if for the 2014-02-03 18:00:00 there are only 2 entries and the third one is NaN) I want the mean to be computed. I want to use the numpy's `nanmean` function:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level=0).nanmean()
```

But `nanmean` is not an attribute of groupby and it doesn't work. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you get same output, because [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) omit `NaN`s - same as `np.nanmean`:

```
print (df)
                     key1  key2   value
2014-02-03 12:00:00  22.0  32.0   98.89
2014-02-03 12:00:00  23.0  33.0   99.25
2014-02-03 12:00:00  24.0  34.0   99.78
2014-02-03 15:00:00  22.0  32.0   96.54
2014-02-03 15:00:00  23.0  33.0   97.21
2014-02-03 15:00:00  24.0  34.0   98.59
2014-02-03 18:00:00  22.0  33.0   97.41
2014-02-03 18:00:00  25.0  40.0  100.00
2014-02-03 18:00:00   NaN   NaN     NaN


grouped = df.groupby(level=0).mean()
print (grouped)
                     key1  key2      value
2014-02-03 12:00:00  23.0  33.0  99.306667
2014-02-03 15:00:00  23.0  33.0  97.446667
2014-02-03 18:00:00  23.5  36.5  98.705000

grouped = df.groupby(level=0).agg(np.nanmean)
print (grouped)
                     key1  key2      value
2014-02-03 12:00:00  23.0  33.0  99.306667
2014-02-03 15:00:00  23.0  33.0  97.446667
2014-02-03 18:00:00  23.5  36.5  98.705000
```

Comment: Yes, I think you're totally right. And thanks for the extra example with ``agg``.

Comment: Thank you. Docs it says also `Compute mean of groups, excluding missing values` - in [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html)